# How do I structure my Polymer SPA and core-pages around my view models?

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer, polymer-1.0

I used to have e.g. `<template if="{{app.router.selectedPage == 'lobby'}}">` around the different Polymer elements that are on their respective pages, but now I've removed them because it's much faster to just let `core-animated-pages` do its thing and flip the `display` property so that the `section` and its children are simply either showing or not, as you see below.

```
        <core-animated-pages id="pages" selected="{{app.router.selectedPage}}" valueattr="data-page" fit>
          <section data-page="channels" layout vertical>
            <community-list id="community-list" app="{{app}}" viewModel="{{app.mainViewModel}}"></community-list>
          </section>
          <section data-page="lobby">
            <chat-view app="{{app}}" viewModel="{{app.mainViewModel.chatViewModel}}"></chat-view>
          </section>
          <section data-page="people" layout vertical>
            <people-list app="{{app}}" viewModel="{{app.mainViewModel.peopleViewModel}}"></people-list>
          </section>
          <section data-page="events">
            <inbox-list id="inbox-list" app="{{app}}" viewModel="{{app.mainViewModel.eventViewModel}}"></inbox-list>
          </section>
          <section data-page="news">
            <inbox-list id="inbox-list" app="{{app}}" viewModel="{{app.mainViewModel.newsViewModel}}"></inbox-list>
          </section>
        </core-animated-pages>
```

I pass getters into the `viewModel` attribute, e.g. `app.mainViewModel.chatViewModel`, which gets the instance of the view model that is appropriate for the given channel/community (I use the two terms interchangeably at this point) we're on – for example, if we're in the "foo" channel, `app.mainViewModel.chatViewModel` returns the chat view model for the "foo" channel.

The problem: I need to somehow trigger the getters for the view models again, whenever the channel changes.

One option is to wrap all the elements that are for a specific channel (i.e. everything besides the channels page itself) in a `<template if="{{app.community != null}}">` so that those elements actually get detached when we're not in a channel and reattached when we choose a new channel, thus re-triggering the getters and returning the relevant view model.

I've verified that works, but I'm trying to go all the way with avoiding `<template>` conditions that destroy and recreate the elements each time.

What are some better ways to approach how I architect this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have just built myself a router and behavior that addresses this problem (see akc42/akc-router on github).

To explain the whole thing is out of scope of this reply, but in simple terms the router in the attach function but after an async wait starts at its parent (which I suppose will be the dom-bind template) and parses the DOM tree looking for all the elements with the "behavior" in them.  It builds a model as a tree of these elements.  URL segments map on to each "behavior".

The key issue, is on a url change (either application invoked, or via user using the back and or forward buttons), the router can use this tree to make calls to the behaviour, which it turn calls the element via an abstract call.

(A quick look at the test of this setup will show quite simply how it is used).

There seems to be a difference in your approach (if I understand your example correctly) in that you are getting one massive model at router level and want each sub element to see part of it.  I have delegated each lower level element to get its part of the model when the router tells it to.  But your core problem, of stimulating the lower level  has been addressed.

I have only just started building it into my project (I was using page.js before, but I was struggling with how it could trigger iron-pages, which is why I built the router).  But the test harness does show it doing the job.